# Oracle - How to select and alias column by column-position, not column-name

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle - How to select and re-alias column by column-position, not column-name?
Exp:

```
SELECT $1 AS NEW_COL_1, $2 AS NEW_COL_2
FROM 
       (SELECT 'x' AS COL_1, 'y' AS COL_2 FROM DUAL)
```

$1, $2 mean col_1, col_2

I have tried google but no solution yet!

Comment: You cannot. SQL does not support that syntax.

Comment: If you know column names upfront, then you may generate new column aliases with the help of code that generates this query. You may also use `with tbl_renamed(col1_new, col2_new) as (select col1, col2 from tab) select * from tbl_renamed`, but it adds not much sense as you have to specify all the columns in the `with`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-hTzyokf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. SQL does not support that syntax.

Comment: So, is there another solution to do that?

Comment: @NgocTrung Another alternative to doing something that is not supported in SQL? No, it is not supported so you cannot do it. Perhaps if you explained why you want to do something like that then we could understand and offer an alternate method but accessing user-defined columns by position is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution like this, but it requires knowing the number of columns:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT NULL NEW_COL1, NULL NEW_COL2
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'x' AS COL_1, 'y' AS COL_2 FROM DUAL
) 
WHERE NEW_COL1 IS NOT NULL;
```